# How to keep my accelerometer working on lock screen (onPause)?

Tags: android, asynchronous, accelerometer, onpause

I'm making an app that reads movement with Android's accelerometer, however I want it to continuously read the data even when phone is locked. Would I just have to put the same code I used in `onSensorChanged()` listener in the `onPause()` method? I read something about Async, but I'm not sure if it works with hardware applications. Which would be the better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) , setup accelerometer and implement SensorEventListener and then everytime this event fires, acquire wake lock. and then send broadcast to activities.

```
public SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{
```

}

hope this helps :)

Comment: So basically don't allow it to lock? Also what if the app is minimized? Thanks.

Comment: just override onStartCommand of Service and return start_sticky.